# Using moment-timezone with webpack

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs, webpack

I have `react`/`redux` application that runs on `webpack` and would like to use `moment-timezone` library. I already checked [How should I use moment-timezone with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548386/how-should-i-use-moment-timezone-with-webpack) issue here in SO and installed `json-loader` as it is described in the issue. But still when requiring `moment-timezone` in my application as:

```
const momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
```

it raises an error:

```
ERROR in ./~/moment-timezone/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /path-to-the-project/node_modules/moment-timezone
 @ ./~/moment-timezone/index.js 2:15-51
```

Where the `@ ./~/moment-timezone/index.js 2:15-51` is:

```
moment.tz.load(require('./data/packed/latest.json'));
```

However when I included the minified version from the build folder it worked properly, as:

```
const momentTz = require('moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.min');
```

#### Update:

webpack configs:

```
let jsonLoader = require('json-loader');
loaders: [
  {
    include: /\.json$/,
    loaders: [jsonLoader]
  }
]
```

Comment: So is there an answer for adding moment-timezone to properly interop with moment so you can use moment.tz()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was that in the `webpack` configurations. The problem was that I required the `json-loader` in the webpack config and passed it as an object instead of string, so changing it to string fixed the issue:

```
loaders: [
  {
    include: /\.json$/,
    loaders: ['json-loader']
  }
]
```