# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack

I have here a webpack config, I am trying to add `moment-timezone` with an answer [How should I use moment-timezone with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548386/how-should-i-use-moment-timezone-with-webpack), which led me to [Webpack - Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266706/webpack-error-cannot-define-query-and-multiple-loaders-in-loaders-list)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve('./assets'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  externals: {
      jquery: 'var jQuery'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['json-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react-hmre'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My current attempt is above.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling webpack to pass your JavaScript files to the `json-loader`. But because JavaScript files are not valid JSON, you get the error that there is an unexpected token already at the first character.

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loaders: ['json-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react-hmre'],
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

So you need to remove the `json-loader` from the `.jsx?` configuration. Additionally `json-loader` isn't require anymore in webpack 2 and JSON files should just work out of the box.

You can update the `module` section to:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react-hmre',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
}
```

But just in case it shouldn't work, you would have to add the `json-loader` for files ending in `.json`:

```
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json-loader'
}
```